# Why I can't INSERT to my database

Tags: php, database, insert

why i can't insert to my database with this code ?? thank you :)

```
<?php 
if ($_GET[act]==''){ 
    if (isset($_POST[simpan])){
        $juml = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rb_siswa where kode_kelas='$_GET[kelas]'"));
        for ($ia=1; $ia<=$juml; $ia++){
          $a   = $_POST['a'.$ia];
          $b   = $_POST['b'.$ia];
          $c   = $_POST['c'.$ia];
          $d   = $_POST['d'.$ia];
          $nisn   = $_POST['nisn'.$ia];
          if ($a != '' OR $b != '' OR $c != '' OR $d != ''){
            $cek = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rb_nilai_harian where id_tahun_akademik='$_POST[tahun]' AND nisn='$nisn' AND kode_kelas='$_POST[kelas]'"));
            if ($cek >= '1'){
              mysql_query("UPDATE rb_nilai_harian SET reseptif_nilai'$a', reseptif_deskripsi='$b', ekspresif_nilai='$c', ekspresif_deskripsi='$d' where id_tahun_akademik='$_POST[tahun]' AND nisn='$nisn' AND kode_kelas='$_POST[kelas]'");
            }else{
              mysql_query("INSERT INTO rb_nilai_harian VALUES('','$_POST[tahun]','$nisn','$_POST[kelas]','$a','$b','$c','$d','$_SESSION[id]','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");
            }
          } 
        }
        echo "<script>document.location='index.php?view=nilaiharian&tahun=".$_POST[tahun]."&kelas=".$_POST[kelas]."';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: You must wrap `act`  and `simpan` in single or double quotes

Comment: In your given code I see one missing closing } for the first if statement (if ($_GET[act]==''){).

Comment: also what ever you do don't use this on a live internet site, it is very unsafe and some one could easily use SQL injection to wreck your databases.